# How to divide Crystal Report output based on page number

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a requirement to produce 3 stacks of pdf based on the page number.

- Page numbers 1-4 go into stack 1
- Page numbers 5-6 go into stack 2
- Page numbers 7+ go into stack 3

Please let me know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to implement the code yourself, the [SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio .NET SDK Developer Guide](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0d6684e153174710b8b2eb114bb7f843/SP21/en-US/45b2712e6e041014910aba7db0e91070.html) is a good start. And there are several PDF libraries you can chose from.

Alternatively, there are 3rd-party Crystal automation tools that may provide that functionality. Ken Hamady maintains a list of such tools at his [web site](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched).

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is in my report page numbers are resetting say as soon as employee number is changing. So for 1 employee there could be 4 pages, for other employee there could be 10 on the same report. Requirement is to divide this single report into 3 different reports based on page numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a formula, which will return 1 for pages 1-4, 2 for pages 5-6, 3 for pages 7+. Then create a group based on this formula and use bursting to export each group to a separate pdfs. You need to use external software for bursting and Ken's website could be a good place find some. This one is free: [R-Tag Community Edition](http://r-tag.com/Pages/CommunityEdition.aspx)

I guess you can also do this manually , by adding a parameter and filtering by the provided parameter value in the group formula.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is in my report page numbers are resetting say as soon as employee number is changing. So for 1 employee there could be 4 pages, for other employee there could be 10 on the same report. Requirement is to divide this single report into 3 different reports based on page numbers.

Comment: Then you will need to create a group based on employee id and page number. The best approach will be using data driven jobs, which will allow you to define a list of employees and run a report for each employee. BTW why do you need everything to be in a single report, create 3 reports or use a parameter and run the same report 3 times exporting different set of pages

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bad choice to approach this problem by trying to target page numbers.
You simply need to "burst" the report so that each employee becomes a separate file export.

You can drive that process in your own code by looping and feeding a different employee id to a report with an employee id as a parameter.

A faster and more powerful approach is to use one of the 3rd-party Crystal automation tools (see my original answer). Some of these tools can do a single-pass report bursting with extra options for naming and emailing the individual output files.